# I have to read value of a key from a text file in C

Tags: c

I have text file, say abc.txt. It has a key : value combination in this manner :

WAN_MODE : ETH

I need to write a function in C to get the value of the variable "WAN_MODE". The result, in this case is "ETH". How can I write a function for this, returning the result value?

Comment: What have You tried so far? Are You able to open the file and read text lines from it?

Comment: Time to review [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be to open the file, read it line by line, split each line with the character ":" and check if the first element of the split is "WAN_MODE". If it is then the second would be the value, else go to the next line.

More about reading files in c: 
http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/getline.3.html

More about the split fonction in c:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/